# Compare all rows depending on several conditions and return value

Tags: r, for-loop, row

I want to compare different cells in different rows and return a value if conditions are satisfied.

Suppose the following   `s_i` =

```
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.43020494 0.7183179 0.4201009
[2,] 0.08625491 0.3007912 0.8768459
[3,] 0.80012649 0.8448729 0.7131344
```

I want to compare all the rows (pairs), so row 1,2; 1,3 ; 2,3; 2,1; 3,1 and row 3,2 
The output `dgpos` contains the row numbers that are combined and the values returned.

I want to compare the rows. for the frist to combination or rows 1 and 2

```
1,  if  2b≥1b
0, if 1a≥2c
(1a-2c )/ ((2b-2c) –(1b-1a), otherwise
```

where a, b and c are the columns of s_i

In R-ish for row 1 and 2

```
If   (s_i[2,2]>= s_i[1,2])
 dgpos[rowindex,3]=1

If   (s_i[1,1]>= s_i[2,3])
dgpos[rowindex,3]=0

else (otherwise)

dgpos[rowindex,3] =(s_i[1,1]- s_i[2,3])/((s_i[2,2]-s_i[2,3])-(s_i[1,2]-s_i[1,1]))
```

The output I want aim for contains the combinations and the values returned in `dgpos[,3]`

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    0.5168453
[2,]    1    3    1
[3,]    2    3    1
[4,]    2    1    1
[5,]    3    1    0
[6,]    3    2    0.1235813
```

I have this:

```
s_i=matrix(runif(9),3)

dgpos=matrix(0,(dim(s_i)[2]*(dim(s_i)[2]-1)),3)

rowindex=1



for (i in 1:nrow(s_i)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(s_i)) {
    if (i!=j)

      c1=s_i[i,]
    c2=s_i[j+1,]

    dgpos[rowindex,1]=i
    dgpos[rowindex,2]=j+1

    if (c2[2] >= c1[2])
      dgpos[rowindex,3]=1

    dgpos[rowindex,3] = ifelse ((c1[1]=c2[3]), 0 , c1[1]-c2[3]/((c2[2]-c2[3])-(c1[2]-c1[1])))

    rowindex=rowindex+1  
  }
 }
```

I know that loops, are not preferred, but at the moment (my level of r-ish) I don’t know a better solution. I have tried `adply` with `combn`, without result.

MQ: how to compare different cells in different rows and return a value depending on several conditions ?

Your help and commends are appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It not very reasonable to ask people to wade through your extended code if its a very inefficient approach to the problem.

Comment: Hi @geotheory. Thank you for the feedback. I understand. I thought “I will show the code I have tried to grasp the idea”. I have tried to explain what I want by using an example in R-ish of two rows.

Comment: Your example input data is fine. Perhaps just give an example of the output data format and we can suggest methods to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not guarantee this is exactly the logic you want (there were inconsistencies between your example and your code) but this is the right approach to vectorize your algorithm:

First, create a data.frame of all row indices combinations:

```
n <- nrow(s_i)
dgpos <- rev(expand.grid(row2 = seq_len(n), row1 = seq_len(n)))
dgpos <- subset(dgpos, row1 != row2)
dgpos
#   row1 row2
# 2    1    2
# 3    1    3
# 4    2    1
# 6    2    3
# 7    3    1
# 8    3    2
```

Then, compute your outcomes in one vectorized call, a nested `ifelse`:

```
dgpos <- transform(dgpos, out = { c1 <- s_i[row1, ]
                                  c2 <- s_i[row2, ]
                                  ifelse(c2[,2] >= c1[,2], 1,
                                  ifelse(c1[,1] >= c2[,3], 0,
                                  (c1[,1]-c2[,3]) / ((c2[,2]-c2[,3]) - (c1[,2]-c1[,1])))) })
dgpos
#   row1 row2 out
# 2    1    2   0
# 3    1    3   0
# 4    2    1   0
# 6    2    3   0
# 7    3    1   0
# 8    3    2   0
```

Comment: flodel. Thank you. I have used your suggestions in a loop, because transform didn’t results in the output I want.

Comment: Thank you @flodel. I have used your suggestions in a loop, because transform didn’t results in the output I want.

Answer (score 0):

This works thanks to @flodel. No doubt, it’s not the most elegant solution

```
dgpos = rev(expand.grid(row2 = seq_len(nrow(s_i)), row1 = seq_len(nrow(s_i))))
dgpos =  subset(dgpos, row1 != row2)

for (i in 1:nrow(dgpos)) {

  c1 = s_i[dgpos$row1[i], ]
  c2 = s_i[dgpos$row2[i], ]

  dgpos$out[i] = ifelse(c2[2] >= c1[2], 1,
           ifelse(c1[1] >= c2[3], 0,
                  (c1[1]-c2[3]) / ((c2[2]-c2[3]) - (c1[2]-c1[1])))) }

dgpos

   # row1 row2       out
   # 2    1    2 0.5168453
   # 3    1    3         1
   # 4    2    1         1
   # 6    2    3         1
   # 7    3    1         0
   # 8    3    2 0.1235813
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to reproduce your desired output using this:

```
f <- function(i, j, s){
    ifelse(s[j,2]>=s[i,2], 1, ifelse(s[i,1]>=s[j,3], 0,
        (s[i,1]-s[j,3])/((s[j,2]-s[j,3])-(s[i,2]-s[i,1]))))
}

s_i <- rbind(
c(0.43020494, 0.7183179, 0.4201009),
c(0.08625491, 0.3007912, 0.8768459),
c(0.80012649, 0.8448729, 0.7131344))

y <- combn(nrow(s_i), 2)

dgpos <- t(cbind(y, y[2:1,]))

cbind(dgpos, f(dgpos[,1], dgpos[,2], s_i))
```

Result:

```
     [,1] [,2]      [,3]
[1,]    1    2 0.5168453
[2,]    1    3 1.0000000
[3,]    2    3 1.0000000
[4,]    2    1 1.0000000
[5,]    3    1 0.0000000
[6,]    3    2 0.1235813
```